# Python :: pandas and json.dumps

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm using pandas to read from an excel and json to create a json.

```
for x in range(1,n)
    label = (df.columns[x]).strip()
    something = (df[df.columns[x]][i])
    print (label)
    print (something)
```

This gives me exactly what I have in the excel I'm reading...

```
productTypes
"APPLE","BANANA"
```

When I do a json.dumps...

```
for x in range(1,n)
    label = (df.columns[x]).strip()
    something = (df[df.columns[x]][i])
    value = json.dumps(something)
    print (label)
    print (value)
```

This gives me

```
productTypes
"\"APPLE\",\"BANANA\""
```

What I need in my json is...

```
"productTypes":["APPLE","BANANA"]
```

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `dict` out of the `label` and `something` and then do the `json.dumps()`

Simple example -

```
import json

label = 'productTypes'
something = ["APPLE","BANANA"]
print(json.dumps({label: something}))
```

**Output**

```
{"productTypes": ["APPLE", "BANANA"]}
```

So in you case, declare a `dict` for `label` and `something`. Something like -

```
for x in range(1,n)
    label = (df.columns[x]).strip()
    something = (df[df.columns[x]][i])
    print (label)
    print (something)
    value = json.dumps({label: something})
```